# iOS NSDateFormatter ignoring timezone

Tags: ios, json, nsdateformatter

I'm currently pulling date/times from a Postgresql database via json and converting the date to an NSDate. I originally saved my date at Jan 15, 12PM PST. Can someone see where in the following process I go wrong ? It seems that on the iOS side its ignoring the timestamp

Originally the date in PostgreSql looks like:

```
2015-01-16 20:00:10+00
```

The date in JSON looks like:

```
"start_time" = "2015-01-16T20:00:10.000Z";
```

And when I convert this date using:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z"];
```

I get

```
  2015-01-17 04:00:10 +0000
```

Which also read:

```
  "start_time" = "2015-01-16 20:00:10 PST in the debugger
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are quoting the timezone format specifier. You want:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
```

Note the lack of quote before the `Z`.

Comment: Wow, thanks that did it ! Guess this is where things like Mantle can really help